# selenium，python，determine whether a manually opened page in the browser contains the specified page

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I have a specific URL, and I have opened multiple pages in Chrome, how to determine if multiple pages contain the previous URL

I use pid to find the page opened, but it is difficult. Then, I use the following code, but I can only find one page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options 
import Options
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:8888")
browser1 = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
print(browser1.title)
```

Comment: are you sure thats your code? open chrome browser and get title without load url?

Comment: Yes， because I have opened the page manually, and I have set the port int the chrome. But I dont't know if I hava opened multiple pages, what should I do?